# Is there a way to build my own vim knowledge base like the help system

Tags: vim, knowledge-management

For example:

```
:Kb js 
   or 
:Kb javascript
```

will lead me to my own javascript page

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can just add additional files to `~/.vim/doc/`. As long as you use Vim's help syntax (`*name*` for tag definitions and `|name|` for links), you just need to update the help database via `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`, and then have your knowledge base available via `:help name`. I personally use that for "cheat pages" for certain filetypes, and to provide summary information for complex plugins.

It should also be possible to put your knowledge base into a separate directory. Then, you would have to reimplement the `:help` command, probably by temporarily directing the `'tags'` value to it and using `:tag`.